# Can I make the lof fit on one page?

Tags: table-of-contents, fit

My list of figures in my thesis is currently 3 lines too long to fit on one page, but this of course looks very ugly as almost a complete page is left white.

Is there a way to make the list fit into one page while still keeping all figures referenced included?

Comment: Did you try inserting the instructions `\clearpage\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}` immediately before `\listoffigures`? A better idea, though, might be to shorten some of the figures' captions.

Comment: EDIT: I thought it worked, but now my last figure reference is on top of my page number, is there a way to make the letters smaller or something such that it still all fits, yet does not interfere with my page number?

The length of the captions weren't a problem, I just had too many figures to fit the list on one page.

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered without seeing the list of figures -- given as a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), of course. This said, you could try using a smaller font for this page. A better option would be to shorten those captions that take up just a little more than one line in the list of figures.

Comment: Yeah, lengthening the text block by three lines runs a serious risk of entangling the bottom-most text with the page number -- which, I gather, is placed bottom-center. (I would definitely not change the placement of the page number: The location of the page numbers is probably governed by your university's layout requirements. Under no circumstance should you mess with them.) Frankly, I suspect you're wasting your time trying to fit the entire list-of-figures material on a single page: No lasting harm will come from letting the final three lines be placed on a separate page.

Comment: Use a smaller font?  The page number uses \normalfont so you will have to redefine that (temporarily) as well.  Use \the\parskip to see if your default definition can be reduced.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't get a blank page anyway?  book class does that.